# How can I take a screenshot with eOS installed on a MacBook?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

I have installed elementaryOS Hera on a MacBook. The issue is that it is not possible to take a screenshot using the shortcut 'print' key, because MacBooks do not have a 'print' key. Instead, I have to use 'Shift+cmd+3, or Shift+cmd+4. They do not work.

I tried using shell commands to take a screenshot `~$ sudo screenshot-tools -r` and `~$ screenshot-tools -rc`, but they did not work either, because *screenshot-tools* cannot be located in the repository and I'm not entirely sure of the app's name to install it.

Essentially, I need to find a way to map the three-keys function of the MacBook to the screenshot Keyboard shortcut of Hera, to enable the facility. I can find no information on how I might map the MacBook screenshot keys to the Hera screenshot because there is no translation or comparison to Windows-compatible laptops, or else, I would use the ASCII (or Unicode) character codes to complete the task.

I would greatly appreciate some help here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: You can assign keys at keyboard settings]

You can set you own Shortcuts in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Screenshots. As for me I just replaced Print key with W key.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it on macbook using definition of new shortcus using instead of print press "eject" because I used to have DVD, but now have tho drives in my mac. This works.. Hotkey shift plus eject makes screenshots